# ID Allocator implementation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

In one of my recent interviews, I was asked to implement an ID allocator.

Here is the problem:

Implement an id allocator class that can allocate ids from the range 0~size-1. There are 2 methods for this class:

1. alloc() - allocates a id that is not being used, returns it.
2. release(id) - takes in an id that is being used, and make it available to be allocated.

The followup requirement was basically to maintain a bit array to save space, however the runtime for both of the methods need to be better than linear. I was stuck on that followup, do you guys have any ideas?

```
from bitarray import bitarray

class id_allocator():

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.ids = bitarray(size) # 0 is available, 1 is unavailable

    def alloc(self):
        for idx, _id in enumerate(self.ids):
            if not _id:
                self.ids[idx] = True
                return idx
        raise Exception('no ids available')

    def release(self, _id):
        if _id > len(self.ids) or self.ids[_id] == True:
            raise Exception('invalid id')
        self.ids[_id] = False
```

Comment: I think your code contains a typo. `release()` should set the value in the bit array to `False`.

Comment: @ndmeiri thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you do not have to use your ids in order, you can do this in constant time by keeping a set of free ids and a set of used ids.

```
class IdAllocator():

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.free_ids = set(range(size))
        self.used_ids = set()

    def alloc(self):
        try:
            id = self.free_ids.pop()
            self.used_ids.add(id)
            return id

        except KeyError:
            raise Exception('No id available')

    def release(self, id):
        if id in self.used_ids:
            self.used_ids.remove(id)
            self.free_ids.add(id)
```

This is not as memory efficient as using `bitarray`, but the *O(1)* time complexity probably outweighs that.